# create a list of objects of different type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have to create a function that receives this
to work with the list parameters

check [c, (x,y,z), c, (x,y,z), ..., c, (x,y,z)]

where c is a integer and (x,y,z) a tuple

but I don't know how to implement the function

Comment: If each `c` is followed by a 3-tuple, why not `[(c, (x, y, z)), (c, (x,y,z)), ...]`?

Comment: You can't really have heterogenous lists like that. Either use a nested tuple if they come in pairs, or a discriminating union type like `Either Integer YourTuple`

Comment: Seeing as you can't create such a list, it seems unlikely that you *have to* create a function that receives them. (This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. A list can only contain values of a single type. You *could* make a `[Either Integer (Integer, Integer, Integer)]`, in which case your list would look like `[Left c1, Right (x1, y1, z1), Left c2, Right (x2, y2, z2)]`, but this isn't very satisfying, will likely be difficult to work with, and can't be enforced by the type system. Remember that the more we allow the type checker to enforce, the less likely we are to run into unexpected values down the line.

Instead, you should consider bracketing the mismatched types into a list of pairs `[(Integer, (Integer, Integer, Integer))]`, which would make the list look like `[(c1, (x1, y1, z1)), (c2, (x2, y2, z2))]`.